# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined express js+jade templating

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, server, pug

I am trying to execute an express example program for form submission using the post request . The code for app.js and index.js is as follows.

app.js

```js
var http=require('http');
var express=require('express');
var app=express()

app.set('view engine','jade');
app.set('views','./views');
app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.render('index');
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    console.log('Name: ' + name);
    console.log('Email: ' + email);
    
 }); 
app.get('/search-result',function(req,res){
 var name=req.query.d_name;
 console.log("name is"+name)
 
})
 

http.createServer(app).listen(3000,function(){
 console.log("started");
})
```

index.jade

```html
html
 head
  title #{title}

 body 
  h1 #{title}
  p Enter the name and email id .

  form(action='/search-result',method='get')
   label Name
   input(type='text',name='d_name')
   input(type='submit',value='Search')

  form(action='/signup',method='post')
   div
    label Name
    input(type='text',name='name')

   div
    label Email
    input(type='text',name='email')
   div
    input(type='submit')
```

In the above scenario I'm successfully able to retrieve the value in the 'd_name' text field and use console.log on using a get method ( /search-result route) by clicking search button. But when I try to use a post method(/signup route)by clicking the submit button to retrieve the value from the 'name' and 'email' text fields   I am getting the following error.

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

It would be great if somebody shed some light on this.!!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

[How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' from Express Nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515511/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-from-express-nodemailer)

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

That line would let you read the post data form

Answer (score 1):

**Simple use this because this built in middleware function in express**

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had totally missed out the body-parser part that has to be included for the post request . Although it was deprecated tweaked it somehow to make it work with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4)

Answer (score 0):

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.use(express.josn());